# Angularjs, component unit testing fail because of unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript

I get `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myComponentDirectiveProvider <- myComponentDirective` in angularjs unit test.

In angularjs official document, there is no description about providing directive. Just add to component by `.component` there.

I think directive is provided by `.directive` method in angularjs.
For component, I think there is no need to provide.

How can I fix this error? Please advice for me.

My codes are below.

component.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../require.d.ts" />

export class MyController {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  $onInit(): void {
  }
}

export let myComponent = {
  template: require('./index.html'),
  controller: MyController,
  bindings: {
    name: "@",
    age: "@",
  }
}
```

app.ts

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

import { myComponent } from './component/index';

angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
  .component('myComponent', myComponent);
```

component.spec.ts

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';

import { MyController } from '../../../src/component/index';

describe('index test', () => {
  let $injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService;
  let $componentController: angular.IComponentControllerService;

  let controller: MyController;

  interface testBindings {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  }

  let bindings: testBindings;

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('myApp');
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    $injector = angular.injector(['ngMock']);
    $componentController = $injector.get<angular.IComponentControllerService>("$componentController");
  })

  it('component: test', () => {
    bindings = { name: 'ko', age: 32 };
    controller = $componentController<MyController, testBindings>('myComponent', null, bindings);

    expect(controller.name).toBe('ko');
    expect(controller.age).toBe(32);
  });
});
```

Comment: I solve by myself. Use IControllerSevice instead of IComponentControllerSevice. And pass to controller constructor function instead of component name. I wonder there is difference JavaScript and TypeScript...